# Running Liquibase GenerateChangeLog command against Oracle database results in idle with no output in log file/console after specific point

Tags: xml, oracle, command-line-interface, liquibase, ojdbc

I am trying to create new Liqubase `DatabaseChangeLog.xml` file against existing Oracle database with specific schemas to grab the db structure from. The goal is to replace existing sql scripts with changeSet format and make Liquibase migrations work on both PostgreSQL and Oracle databases.

I have specified my `liquibase.properties` file as:

```
changeLogFile: DatabaseChangelog.xml
schemas: schema1,schema2,schema3
driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
classpath: ojdbc8.jar
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID
username: User
password: PASSWORD
logLevel: debug
logFile: log.txt
```

When i do `liquibase generateChangeLog` in cli, i get the following output:

```
Liquibase Community 4.0.0 by Datical
Starting Liquibase at 12:44:52 (version 4.0.0 #19 built at 2020-07-13 19:45+0000)
```

and after some time it outputs an error:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID with driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.  Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
For more information, please use the --logLevel flag
```

the output of log.txt contains no error messages, and it seems that liquibase is well connected to the database, but log ends unexpectedly.
Here is a piece of log:

```
[2020-09-14 12:44:52] FINE [liquibase.database] Properties:
[2020-09-14 12:44:52] FINE [liquibase.database] Key:'password' Value:'**********'
[2020-09-14 12:44:52] FINE [liquibase.database] Key:'user' Value:'USER'
[2020-09-14 12:44:52] FINE [liquibase.database] Connecting to the URL:'jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID' using driver:'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
[2020-09-14 12:44:52] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.DatabaseConnection instance liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection
[2020-09-14 12:44:52] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.DatabaseConnection instance com.datical.liquibase.ext.database.jvm.ProJdbcConnection
[2020-09-14 12:44:59] FINE [liquibase.database] Connection has been created
[2020-09-14 12:45:00] FINE [liquibase.database] Connected to USER@jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID
[2020-09-14 12:45:00] FINE [liquibase.database] Setting auto commit to false from true
...
[2020-09-14 12:45:40] FINE [liquibase.executor] Executing with the 'jdbc' executor
```

Last line is the last one in log file.

Liquibase version is `Community 4.0.0`, oracle driver is `ojdbc8.jar`.

I have `ojdbc8.jar` in the same dirrectory as `liquibase.properties`.

DB and user credentials are correct, and i can connect to the database with DBForge (in `tnsnames.ora` format with the same address and user credentials).

Did anyone had the same problem trying to create new `DatabaseChangeLog.xml` from existing oracle database? I will be glad to see any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

**Edited**:
Actually it gave me an output after 1 hr of working:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No data to read from socket
For more information, please use the --logLevel flag
```

But there is data/tables in the schemas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command-line tool for generating the changelogs from the existing schema.
Use following command and be-aware of extra spaces as liquibase will complain about that.

Make sure to copy the `ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar` in the **lib** folder of liquibase-zip downloaded from below mentioned location.
I have downloaded the liquibase.zip from here and used the following command
[liquibase_zip](https://www.liquibase.org/download)

```
liquibase.bat --driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl" --username=TEST_A --password=test --changeLogFile=db.test.xml generateChangeLog
```

**Or**
you can use the same method.I have replace the properties like this in liquibase.properties file and it is working fine.Note there is no space between

> key=value

```
changeLogFile=DatabaseChangelog.xml
schemas=TEST
driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/service_name
username=TEST_A
password=password
logLevel=debug
logFile=log.txt
```

For SID replace the URL like this

```
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:sid
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I have replaced properties the way you mentioned with no spaces and '=' notation, but i still get same result.
Using slash `/` instead of semicolon `:` right before the SID in the url also not affected the behaviour of generateChangeLog command.
I have also tried to use other versions of ojdbc.jar with no success.

Comment: Are you getting the same error?Can you try generating changelogs for one schema and see.Did you tried the first approach?